# Membership reboot web api controller async issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem which(I guess) may be related with api controller.

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private readonly UserAccountService<HierarchicalUserAccount> userAccountService;
    private readonly AuthenticationService<HierarchicalUserAccount> authSvc;

    public AccountController(AuthenticationService<HierarchicalUserAccount> authSvc)
    {
        authSvc = authSvc;
        userAccountService = authSvc.UserAccountService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        ...
        HierarchicalUserAccount account;
        if (userAccountService.AuthenticateWithUsernameOrEmail("name@mail.com", "123456", out account))
        {
            authSvc.SignIn(account, false); //ERROR because authSvc is null
        }
        return await ... ;
    }
```

When constructor called userAccountService and authSvc get their values, but in get method authSvc becomes null and userAccountService works as expect.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you registered your authentication service with your dependency injection container? Does your controller contain a default constructor that doesn't initialize `authSvc`?

Comment: IOC Config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292971/membership-reboot-replace-ninject-with-simple-injector

Comment: I have no default constructor

Comment: @peer this question isn't related to the question you mention as duplicate. The OP knows the field is NULL and asks why this is so in the context of ASP.NET Web API initialization.

Comment: @MaxD then have you registered the service? Which DI container do you use? Can you post its initialization code?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292971/membership-reboot-replace-ninject-with-simple-injector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66399/discussion-between-maxd-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
public AccountController(AuthenticationService<HierarchicalUserAccount> authSvc)
{
    authSvc = authSvc;
    userAccountService = authSvc.UserAccountService;
}
```

You are assigning the *local variable* `authSvc` back to itself. You want to assign the class-level field:

```
public AccountController(AuthenticationService<HierarchicalUserAccount> authSvc)
{
    this.authSvc = authSvc;
    userAccountService = authSvc.UserAccountService;
}
```

You can avoid this confusion in future by using proper naming conventions (prefix private fields with an underscore).

```
private readonly AuthenticationService<HierarchicalUserAccount> _authSvc;
```